# Un symmetric bootstrap layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am new to bootstrap.I need help with Bootstrap row/column ordering.
I have a 3 rows and 2 columns of images and text for each image:

### Web Layout:

Image1     Text1

Text2      Image2

Image3     Text3

Web Layout is fine. However, on mobile device it looks (as expected):

Image1

Text1

Text2

Image2

Image3

Text3

I want the mobile layout will be something like:

Image1

Text1

Image2

Text2

Image3

Text3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bootstrap's `push` and `pull` classes like this..

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Image1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Text1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">Image2</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">Text2</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Image3</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Text3</div>
    </div>
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/86DRUFtMmR

Answer (score 2):

This is a default behaviour in Bootstrap - Take a look at 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

you can use push and pull classes to re-order the columns on collapse